# Knockout "Select" not resetting selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have following knockout binding and view model,

```
var productionLineViewModel = {
  ProductionLineInfoList: ko.observableArray([]),
  SelectedProductionLineID: ko.observable(0)
};
```

```html
<select id="drpProductionLine" class="form-control-sm pull-xs-right add-btn" data-bind="options: ProductionLineInfoList, optionsText: 'ProductionLineName', optionsValue: 'ProductionLineID', value: SelectedProductionLineID" style="width: 150px;"></select>
```

This works properly, but when i come back to this screen from the next page (using browser back button), the previously selected value is displaying as selected text.
But the selected value is different.

How to clear avoid knockout from preserving previously selected text?

Comment: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/253

Comment: When i come back to this screen, the previously selected values is displaying, which i don't want